# How do I keep same iframe background in revealjs for multiple slides without reloading?

Tags: leaflet, r-markdown, rstudio, reveal.js

I am using quarto and Rstudio to set up a RevealJS presentation.  I have a leaflet map background iframe and I would like to keep it the same for multiple slides without reloading it every time I change slides, which is what it currently does.  This way the transitions would look much smoother.  Anyone have some idea on how to keep it constant?